# Calling HTML code within PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following .PHP code that contains a table in the HTML tags. The code is for an accident report that should return the users input if completed correctly. If the user does not complete the fields, then the code will return an error message and allow the user to try and fill out the report again.

The way the php code is currently written I am able to return the error message if the report doesn't meet the requirements, but I can't seem to return the list of users input when the report is filled out correctly.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!---Main Content--->
<div id= "content"> 
 <h3> Report a Wildlife Road Collison</h3>
<!---Start of php code--->

<?php 
  $species1 = $_POST['species'];
  $species2 = $_POST['txtSpecies']; 

  $reportDate = $_POST['reportDate'];

  $address = $_POST['address'];

  $lat = $_POST['lat']; 

  $long = $_POST['long'];

  $gender = $_POST['rbGender'];

  $age = $_POST['age'];

// Checking to see if Other was selected by user. If this is true, the user input will be put in the other field.

if($species1 === "Other")
   $species1 = $species2;

//checking for empty fields

if(!empty($species1)&& is_string($species1)&& !empty($location)&& is_string($location) && isset($latitude) && is_numeric($latitude) && isset($longitude) && is_numeric($longitude))
  {

?> <!---end of php code--->

<!---HTML code --->
 <p>Your Information has been Recorded</p>
 <dl>
        <dt>Species</dt>
        <dd><?php print $species1; ?></dd>

        <dt>Date of Incident</dt>
        <dd><?php print $reportDate; ?></dd>

        <dt>Address of Incident</dt>
        <dd><?php print $address; ?></dd>

        <dt>Latitude</dt>
        <dd><?php print $lat; ?></dd>

        <dt>Longitude</dt>
        <dd><?php print $long; ?></dd>

        <dt>Gender</dt>
        <dd><?php print $gender; ?></dd>

        <dt>Age</dt>
        <dd><?php print $age; ?></dd>


    <!---HTML code complete---> 
 </dl> <!---HTML code end--->

    <!---Start PHP code--->
 <?php

}
else{
    print "<h4>Sorry</h4>";
    print "<p>You didn't fill out the form completely.  <a href='index.php?action=report_collision'>Try again?</a></p>";
}


?>
</div>   
</html>
```

I have attempted to assign the html code portion to a variable and call it in the php tag, but I am not clear how that is done correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you always end up in the `else`?

Comment: Please simplify your code example to the minimum example that showcases your problem.

Comment: Yes chris85, I know I should probably add another if statement or maybe elseif?

Answer (score 1):

use echo instead of print. 
like

```
<dd><?php print $age; ?></dd>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a condition checking for

`if(!empty($species1)&& is_string($species1)&& !empty($location)&& is_string($location) && isset($latitude) && is_numeric($latitude) && isset($longitude) && is_numeric($longitude))`

That way, even if only one of the values is empty/not set properly, you end up in else. What you should rather do is check for each of the variables individually. If any of them has none or wrong output, you set them to default and display both the error message and table.

Short example:

```
$everything_ok = true;
$species = 'Wrong value'; //default
if(isset($_POST['species'])) {
    $species1 = $_POST['species'];
} else {
    $everything_ok = false;
}

if(!$everything_ok) {
    //display error
}

//Display the table regardless of if everything is ok. $species will display 'Wrong value'
```

Comment: I see your point, but I would like the error to return even if its just one wrong field and provide the users input if only all the fields are correct.

Comment: @TiffanyMorris: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. In that case I would guess that even when the whole report is filled, it is not filled correctly. Probably latitude/longitude will not be numeric (or not considered numeric). Probably because of whitespace. However, it is a user friendly practice to provide the input back to user. That way he does not have to fill in all the values again, but only "the wrong ones".

Answer (score 0):

In your if condition you are testing on many variables that I cannot see anywhere in your code.

```
isset($latitude) && is_numeric($latitude) && isset($longitude) && is_numeric($longitude)
```

Maybe $long instead of $longitude and $lat instead of $latitude?

Answer (score 0):

I guess their is error in your if condition , you are 
using

```
!empty($location)&& is_string($location) && isset($latitude) && is_numeric($latitude) && isset($longitude) && is_numeric($longitude)
```

but you are getting in your post

```
$lat = $_POST['lat']; 

  $long = $_POST['long'];
```

I guess you have missed some variable declaration in created a wrong if else block

or you have pasted your script incorrectly in the question. Otherwise the way you have done it seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can read in a section of HTML from a file and echo it out.  For example:

```
<h2> pure html here </h2>
<?php
$myfile = fopen("header.html", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("header.html"));
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it always go in else statement because your if condition fails. Check your if condition

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code by removing the html tag and converting the code to php syntax. Everything works now. Thanks for all of the input.